# How to build a CD ISO image file from the windows command line?

Tags: windows, build-process, build-automation, iso

In an effort to satisfy "The Joel Test" question #2 "Can you make a build in one step?", I'm trying to complete a release candidate build script with the creation of a CD iso from the collection of files gathered and generated by the installer creator.

There seem to be many good tools (many free) out there that will create ISOs, but I need to find one that can be run at the windows command line so I can integrate it into the NAnt build script that's fired off by Cruise Control.

Build environment is:

- Windows Server 2003
- .NET 1.1 - 3.5 (application we're creating is built on 2.0)
- NullSoft installer (NSIS)
- CruiseControl.net
- NAnt

I've been googling around, but no luck yet.

Anyone have a recommendation?

Answer (score 17):

Try mkisofs. It's part of the [cdrecord](http://freshmeat.net/projects/cdrecord/) project.

Comment: Win32 binaries can be found here: http://opensourcepack.blogspot.co.il/p/cdrtools.html (links here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tumagcc/files/)

Answer (score 14):

Blatant plug, but I've just released an alpha version of an OpenSource C# library that can create ISO files.  Doesn't directly integrate with Nant, but you could wrap up the library to achieve that.  Theres a sample app (ISOCreate) that creates ISOs from a directory structure, but this sample could also get you started:

```
CDBuilder builder = new CDBuilder();
builder.UseJoliet = true;
builder.VolumeIdentifier = "A_SAMPLE_DISK";
builder.AddFile(@"Folder\Hello.txt", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World!"));
builder.Build(@"C:\temp\sample.iso");
```

[.NET DiscUtils](https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils) (on GitHub)

Answer (score 14):

### Creating a simple CD ISO

I've found a *significantly* easier approach, and it doesn't require Cygwin: **[CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/)**

It's not really advertised on the site, but it includes a command-line edition, as `cdbxpcmd.exe`. There is also [some documentation about the command-line options](http://cdburnerxp.se/help/Appendices/commandlinearguments).

Of particular interest are the `-iso` and `-format` options; used something like:

```
cdbxpcmd --burn-data -folder:input -iso:output.iso -format:iso -changefiledates
```

to generate an ISO called `output.iso` from the files in the `input` folder

---

### Creating a Bootable ISO

The command line tool doesn't appear to let you make a bootable CD directly. However, if you know your list of files isn't going to change (ie only the content of those files), you could try the following (untested):

- Load up the CDBurnerXP GUI version
- Add the files interactively
- Select Disc->Burn Options...
- Set up your boot image
- Select File->Save to create a DXP file (which is CDBurnerXP's compilation format)

Then, you can use the following command

```
cdbxpcmd --burn-data -layout:mycompilation.dxp -iso:output.iso -format:iso
```

Comment: I tried the other tools and found this to be the best option.

Comment: If anybody tries the bootable bit, please comment with your success or otherwise

Comment: To actually make an ISO image (rather then UDF image) you need to use `-format:iso` option. So it's: `cdbxpcmd.exe --burn-data -format:iso -layout:"saved-project.dxp" -iso:"output.iso"`. Note: you will need to update to 4.5.

Answer (score 12):

Get `mkisofs` [here](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/cdrecord.html) - it is part of cdrtools. Available for most platforms.

USAGE examples:

```
mkisofs -v -dvd-video -V "VOLUME_NAME" -o "c:\my movies\iso\movie.iso" "c:\my movies\dvd"
mkisofs -r -R -J -l -L -o image-file.iso c:\project\install
```

Answer (score 8):

Powershell can create an ISO. The below example includes a GUI. Credit to http://blog.apps.id.au/?p=5321

[image]

```
# Author: Hrisan Dzhankardashliyski
# Date: 20/05/2015

# Inspiration from
#
#   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opticalstorage/archive/2010/08/13/writing-optical-discs-using-imapi-2-in-powershell.aspx</a>
#
# and
#
#   http://tools.start-automating.com/Install-ExportISOCommand/</a>
#
# with help from
#
#   http://stackoverflow.com/a/9802807/223837</a>

$InputFolder = ""

function WriteIStreamToFile([__ComObject] $istream, [string] $fileName)
{
# NOTE: We cannot use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream],
# since PowerShell apparently cannot convert an IStream COM object to this
# Powershell type.  (See <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037299/223837">http://stackoverflow.com/a/9037299/223837</a> for
# details.)
#
# It turns out that .NET/CLR _can_ do this conversion.
#
# That is the reason why method FileUtil.WriteIStreamToFile(), below,
# takes an object, and casts it to an IStream, instead of directly
# taking an IStream inputStream argument.

$cp = New-Object CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
$cp.CompilerOptions = "/unsafe"
$cp.WarningLevel = 4
$cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = $true

Add-Type -CompilerParameters $cp -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

namespace My
{

public static class FileUtil {
public static void WriteIStreamToFile(object i, string fileName) {
IStream inputStream = i as IStream;
FileStream outputFileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName);
int bytesRead = 0;
int offset = 0;
byte[] data;
do {
data = Read(inputStream, 2048, out bytesRead);
outputFileStream.Write(data, 0, bytesRead);
offset += bytesRead;
} while (bytesRead == 2048);
outputFileStream.Flush();
outputFileStream.Close();
}

unsafe static private byte[] Read(IStream stream, int toRead, out int read) {
byte[] buffer = new byte[toRead];
int bytesRead = 0;
int* ptr = &bytesRead;
stream.Read(buffer, toRead, (IntPtr)ptr);
read = bytesRead;
return buffer;
}
}

}
"@

[My.FileUtil]::WriteIStreamToFile($istream, $fileName)
}

# The Function defines the ISO parameturs and writes it to file
function createISO([string]$VolName,[string]$Folder,[bool]$IncludeRoot,[string]$ISOFile){

# Constants from <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364840.aspx">http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364840.aspx</a>
$FsiFileSystemISO9660   = 1
$FsiFileSystemJoliet    = 2
$FsiFileSystemUDF      = 4

$fsi = New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2FS.MsftFileSystemImage

#$fsi.FileSystemsToCreate = $FsiFileSystemISO9660 + $FsiFileSystemJoliet

$fsi.FileSystemsToCreate = $FsiFileSystemUDF
#When FreeMediaBlocks is set to 0 it allows the ISO file to be with unlimited size
$fsi.FreeMediaBlocks = 0
$fsi.VolumeName = $VolName

$fsi.Root.AddTree($Folder, $IncludeRoot)

WriteIStreamToFile $fsi.CreateResultImage().ImageStream $ISOFile
}

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)

{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")

$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
{
$folder += [string]$foldername.SelectedPath
}
return $folder
}

# Show an Open Folder Dialog and return the directory selected by the user.
function Read-FolderBrowserDialog([string]$Message, [string]$InitialDirectory, [switch]$NoNewFolderButton)
{
$browseForFolderOptions = 0
if ($NoNewFolderButton) { $browseForFolderOptions += 512 }
$app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, $Message, $browseForFolderOptions, $InitialDirectory)
if ($folder) { $selectedDirectory = $folder.Self.Path }
else { $selectedDirectory = '' }
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app) > $null
return $selectedDirectory
}

#Prompts the user to save the ISO file, if the files does not exists it will create it otherwise overwrite without prompt
Function Get-SaveFile($initialDirectory)
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
Out-Null

$SaveFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$SaveFileDialog.CreatePrompt = $false
$SaveFileDialog.OverwritePrompt = $false
$SaveFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$SaveFileDialog.filter = "ISO files (*.iso)| *.iso"
$SaveFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
$SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$SaveFileDialog.filename
}

# Show message box popup and return the button clicked by the user.
function Read-MessageBoxDialog([string]$Message, [string]$WindowTitle, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]$Buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]$Icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::None)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
return [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message, $WindowTitle, $Buttons, $Icon)
}

# GUI interface for the PowerShell script
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  #loading the necessary .net libraries (using void to suppress output)

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    #creating the form (this will be the "primary" window)
$Form.Text = "ISO Creator Tool:"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,300)  #the size in px of the window length, height
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false
$Form.MinimizeBox = $false

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,20)
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$objLabel.Text = "Please select a Folder:"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel)

$InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)
$InputBox.Enabled = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox)

$objLabel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,80)
$objLabel2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$objLabel2.Text = "ISO File Name:"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel2)

$InputBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,80)
$InputBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)
$InputBox2.Enabled = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox2)

$objLabel3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50)
$objLabel3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$objLabel3.Text = "ISO Volume Name:"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel3)

$InputBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
$InputBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox3)

$objLabel4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,120)
$objLabel4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$objLabel4.Text = "Status Msg:"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel4)

$InputBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$InputBox4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
$InputBox4.Enabled = $false
$InputBox4.Text = "Set ISO Parameters..."
$InputBox4.BackColor = "LimeGreen"
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox4)

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(470,20)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$Button.Text = "Browse"
$Button.Add_Click({
$InputBox.Text=Read-FolderBrowserDialog
$InputBox4.Text = "Set ISO Parameters..."

})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

$Button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(470,120)
$Button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,80)
$Button2.Text = "CreateISO"
$Button2.Add_Click({

if(($InputBox.Text -eq "") -or ($InputBox3.Text -eq "")){
Read-MessageBoxDialog "You have to select folder and specify ISO Volume Name" "Error: No Parameters entered!"
} else{
$SaveDialog = Get-SaveFile
#If you click cancel when save file dialog is called
if ($SaveDialog -eq ""){
return
}
$InputBox2.Text= $SaveDialog
$InputBox2.Refresh()
if($checkBox1.Checked){
$includeRoot=$true
}
else{
$includeRoot=$false
}
$InputBox4.BackColor = "Red"
$InputBox4.Text = "Generating ISO File!"
$InputBox4.Refresh()
createISO $InputBox3.Text $InputBox.Text $includeRoot $InputBox2.Text
$InputBox4.BackColor = "LimeGreen"
$InputBox4.Text = "ISO Creation Finished!"
$InputBox4.Refresh()
}
})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button2)

$objLabel5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,160)
$objLabel5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$objLabel5.Text = "Check the box if you want to include the top folder:"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel5)

$checkBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,156)
$Form.Controls.Add($checkBox1)

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: For the record, this is based on 'my' public domain code from https://gist.github.com/marnix/3944688 .

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be Microsoft addictive (not install additional software). You can use IMAPI, build into Windows to burn images. Additional information regarding scripting IMAPI [can be found in MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/imapi/imapi2-1.mspx)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8324075/223837 for more detail about this approach.

Comment: For a working code sample, a PowerShell script which uses IMAPI, see https://gist.github.com/3944688.

Answer (score 3):

I've used magiciso, but haven't tested it extensivly.  (I may try some of the others mentioned here after some testing) I first make an installer (single file) then just make this an iso.

http://www.magiciso.com/

Here's the result of my struggle to get this working in python:

```
add_option = '-a'
add_option_value = installer_fullpath
response_option = '-py' # answer yes to all options 


# Get the tempfile name -- to resolve long name issue
# --> My file names were initially too long for MagicIso and it would choke
f_handle = tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix='.iso', prefix='mi_', dir='.')
temp_filename = f_handle.name
f_handle.close() # File automatically deleted on close                                

args = (magiciso_exe_fullpath,temp_filename,response_option,add_option,add_option_value)

# log output to file
magiciso_con_f = open(MAGICISO_CON_LOG,'w')

magiciso_process = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=magiciso_con_f,stderr=magiciso_con_f)
magiciso_process.wait()
```

Comment: mksiofs is turning out to be a bit of a pain in the ass to build.  I think we may go with magiciso

Answer (score 2):

I am using `mkisofs.exe` from the installation kit of [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/download.html) or [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/#download), from where I also learned the required parameters for building a bootable cd.