# How to update a DMG file from Windows

Tags: windows, macos, dmg

Just like Peter who looked for a solution to [automate the creation of an ISO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223316/how-to-build-a-cd-iso-image-file-from-the-windows-command-line) file, I am looking for a solution which would allow me to update the contents of a compressed DMG file, originally created on a Mac.

I am aware of several tools which allow me to open a DMG file under Windows (for instance [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org) or [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm)), but they don't seem to be able to update the contents of a compressed DMG file. And moreover, I really need to be able to do this from my build scripts, which have to run on Windows.

Note: I've read Michele's question ([How to build a DMG Mac OS X file on a non-Mac platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform)) but this does not solve the updating of a compressed DMG file.

How could I fully automate my build?

If I cannot handle this on Windows, is there maybe some way to script this on a Mac, and then remotely launch the script from a Windows machine, in order to update the DMG directly on the Mac without human intervention? Running the build server on VMware or Parallels, inside a Mac, is possible for me, if this eases the *remoting* part...

Comment: As far as I know, compressed DMGs are fixed-size and read-only, even on a Mac. To modify the contents of one, I copy it to an uncompressed DMG, mount that and make the changes, then unmount it and make a new compressed copy. Because this process is such a PITA, I generally don't create the final compressed DMG until its contents are finalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my environment, I create from scratch a new DMG for every rebuild. I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/27631/sherm-pendley

Comment: So you have no known way to fully automate the process? I hate it when a human has to do some steps in a process: this is always error prone and a single-click compile, build and package is so much nicer to have...

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I have no other option.