# PowerShell: how to convert a COM object to an .NET interop type?

Tags: powershell, com, powershell-2.0, com-interop

As described in my question [Create ISO image using PowerShell: how to save IStream to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324075), in PowerShell I create an [`IStream`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/aa380034) object as follows:

```
$is = (New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2FS.MsftFileSystemImage).CreateResultImage().ImageStream
```

This object is of (PowerShell) type `System.__ComObject`.  And somehow PowerShell knows that it is an `IStream`:

```
PS C:\> $is -is [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IConnectionPoint]
False
PS C:\> $is -is [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream]
True
```

However, a cast to this type fails:

```
PS C:\> [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream] $is
Cannot convert the "System.__ComObject" value of type "System.__ComObject" to type "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComT
ypes.IStream".
At line:1 char:54
+ [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream] $is <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

How do I make this conversion work, without using C# code?

**Update:** Apparently this conversion cannot be made to work, as x0n's answer says.

Now, my goal is to pass this `IStream` COM object to some C# code (part of the same PowerShell script using `Add-Type`), where it would become a .NET object of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream`.  Is that possible?  If not, what alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to pass `$is` in a (unsafe) c# method like an `object`type and try to handle it with a `VAR`declared as `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream`

```
public unsafe static class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod(object Stream) 
    {
       var i = Stream as System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream; 

    //do something with i like i.read(...) and i.write(...)
    }
}
```

In powershell after the add-type:

```
[MyClass]::MyMethod($is)
```

Comment: And that works!  Previously I had `MyMethod(IStream i)`, and then PowerShell does the conversion to an `IStream`, and fails.  Letting .NET/CLR do the conversion instead, as you suggest, works.  Bounty is coming your way.

Answer (score 5):

You can't make this work. PowerShell uses a transparent "com adapter" layer that prevents this from working, but enables late binding in script. For the majority of cases this a Good Thing, but not in yours.

Comment: Thanks! I'd appreciate an update of your answer to include a pointer to some more documentation on the feature/behavior which you're describing.  Also, my goal is to use this `IStream` COM object in some C# code which is inlined in the same PowerShell script using `Add-Type`, and the C# code needs to read from the `IStream`.  (I'll update this question soon.)  What would be a simple way to do that?

Comment: Check my profile - I am a 5 year powershell microsoft mvp with direct access to the powershell team. I know ;)